# How to click on the element with text as SRP Banner as per the html through Selenium and VBA?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on href using selenium vba in webpage but i am getting below error message.

below is the code which i have tried.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Driver As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
    Driver.Get "http://sums.99acres.com/sums/?profilename=sums"
    Driver.FindElementByName("userlogin") _
    .SendKeys("xyz") _
    .Submit
    Driver.FindElementByName("password") _
    .SendKeys("12345") _
    .Submit
    Driver.Get "http://sums.99acres.com/sums/getmyproducts.php?trans_id=1819-T0639786"
    Driver.Wait 5000
    Driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[contains(@class,'navlink')][contains(text(),'SRP Banner')]").Click
End Sub
```

I have also tried

```
Driver.FindElementByLinkText("SRP Banner").Click
```

Below is the error message i have received

[image]

Below is the screen shot where i want to click

[image]

Below is the html code.

```html
<frame src="http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php?cid=547e14073e8fca793e4629a2acca12c5Si13489029+1534998765+1534998792&amp;trans_id=1819-T0639786" name="left" frameborder="1">
<html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="https://bam.nr-data.net/1/1621b6db8b?a=103016861&amp;v=1071.385e752&amp;to=NV1TZkBVXBdVWk1RVgwXZEBbG0ERWUoWSEsNXERRRkdtC1JfXEpcBhZBWkI%3D&amp;rst=847&amp;ref=http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php&amp;ap=736&amp;be=817&amp;fe=840&amp;dc=839&amp;perf=%7B%22timing%22:%7B%22of%22:1534998816389,%22n%22:0,%22f%22:0,%22dn%22:0,%22dne%22:0,%22c%22:0,%22ce%22:0,%22rq%22:13,%22rp%22:798,%22rpe%22:801,%22dl%22:803,%22di%22:838,%22ds%22:838,%22de%22:839,%22dc%22:839,%22l%22:839,%22le%22:840%7D,%22navigation%22:%7B%7D%7D&amp;at=GRpQEAhPTxk%3D&amp;jsonp=NREUM.setToken"></script><script src="https://js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1071.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,t,n){function r(n){if(!t[n]){var o=t[n]={exports:{}};e[n][0].call(o.exports,function(t){var o=e[n][1][t];return r(o||t)},o,o.exports)}return t[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);return r}({1:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function o(e,t,n){return function(){return i(e,[f.now()].concat(u(arguments)),t?null:this,n),t?void 0:this}}var i=e("handle"),a=e(2),u=e(3),c=e("ee").get("tracer"),f=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var p=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],d="api-",l=d+"ixn-";a(p,function(e,t){s[t]=o(d+t,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=o(d+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=o(d+"routeName",!0),t.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,t){var n={},r=this,o="function"==typeof t;return i(l+"tracer",[f.now(),e,n],r),function(){if(c.emit((o?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[f.now(),r,o],n),o)try{return t.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw c.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],n),e}finally{c.emit("fn-end",[f.now()],n)}}}};a("setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,t){m[t]=o(l+t)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),i("err",[e,f.now()])}},{}],2:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){var n=[],r="",i=0;for(r in e)o.call(e,r)&&(n[i]=t(r,e[r]),i+=1);return n}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],3:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){t||(t=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,o=n-t||0,i=Array(o<0?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=e[t+r];return i}t.exports=r},{}],4:[function(e,t,n){t.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function o(e){function t(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?c(e,u,i):i()}function n(n,r,o,i){if(!d.aborted||i){e&&e(n,r,o);for(var a=t(o),u=m(n),c=u.length,f=0;f<c;f++)u[f].apply(a,r);var p=s[y[n]];return p&&p.push([b,n,r,a]),a}}function l(e,t){v[e]=m(e).concat(t)}function m(e){return v[e]||[]}function w(e){return p[e]=p[e]||o(n)}function g(e,t){f(e,function(e,n){t=t||"feature",y[n]=t,t in s||(s[t]=[])})}var v={},y={},b={on:l,emit:n,get:w,listeners:m,context:t,buffer:g,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function i(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(d.aborted=!0,s=d.backlog={})}var u="nr@context",c=e("gos"),f=e(2),s={},p={},d=t.exports=o();d.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){if(o.call(e,t))return e[t];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,t,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(i){}return e[t]=r,r}var o=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n,r){o.buffer([e],r),o.emit(e,t,n)}var o=e("ee").get("handle");t.exports=r,r.ee=o},{}],id:[function(e,t,n){function r(e){var t=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==t&&"function"!==t?-1:e===window?0:a(e,i,function(){return o++})}var o=1,i="nr@id",a=e("gos");t.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,t,n){function r(){if(!x++){var e=h.info=NREUM.info,t=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(s.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&t))return s.abort();f(y,function(t,n){e[t]||(e[t]=n)}),c("mark",["onload",a()+h.offset],null,"api");var n=d.createElement("script");n.src="https://"+e.agent,t.parentNode.insertBefore(n,t)}}function o(){"complete"===d.readyState&&i()}function i(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+h.offset],null,"api")}function a(){return E.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(u=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),u))-h.offset}var u=(new Date).getTime(),c=e("handle"),f=e(2),s=e("ee"),p=window,d=p.document,l="addEventListener",m="attachEvent",w=p.XMLHttpRequest,g=w&&w.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:p.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:w,REQ:p.Request,EV:p.Event,PR:p.Promise,MO:p.MutationObserver};var v=""+location,y={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1071.min.js"},b=w&&g&&g[l]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),h=t.exports={offset:u,now:a,origin:v,features:{},xhrWrappable:b};e(1),d[l]?(d[l]("DOMContentLoaded",i,!1),p[l]("load",r,!1)):(d[m]("onreadystatechange",o),p[m]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",u],null,"api");var x=0,E=e(4)},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script>
<title>SUMS : MAINPAGE</title>

<style>
a:link, a:visited, a:active{color:#0000ff;}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family:verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000;font-size:11px;">

<br><br><br>
<table width="80%" align="center" style="font-family:verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000;font-size:11px;">
<tbody><tr><td>
<table width="100%" aligh="center"><tbody><tr align="center">
<td width="25%" style="color:#9400D3;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;"><a href="../sums/mainpage.php">SUMS</a></td>
<td width="25%" style="color:#9400D3;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;"><a href="../crm/mainpage.php?checksum=547e14073e8fca793e4629a2acca12c5Si13489029+1534998765+1534998807" onclick="parent.location='http://sums.99acres.com/crm/mainpage.php?checksum=547e14073e8fca793e4629a2acca12c5Si13489029+1534998765+1534998807'">CRM</a></td>
<td width="25%" style="color:#9400D3;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;"><a href="../sums_mis/mainpage.php?name=vishal&amp;cid=547e14073e8fca793e4629a2acca12c5Si13489029+1534998765+1534998807">Mis</a></td>
<td width="25%" style="color:#9400D3;font-size:14px;text-decoration:underline;"><a href="../sums/logout.php" onclick="parent.location='http://sums.99acres.com/sums/'"><!--a href="../sums/logout.php?name=vishal&cid=547e14073e8fca793e4629a2acca12c5Si13489029+1534998765+1534998807" -->Logout</a></td>
</tr></tbody></table><br>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<br><br><table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="font-family:verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#000;font-size:11px;">
<tbody><tr>  <td colspan="2" style="color:#ff6600;font-weight:bold;font-size:18px;">PRODUCTS OFFERED</td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="19">1.</td>
<td width="374"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; FONT-FAMILY: 'Tahoma','sans-serif'"><b><a href="#"></a><a target="right" href="http://sums.99acres.com/sums/zedo_srp_products.php?module=SUMS&amp;trans_id=1819-T0639786&amp;productType=SRPB&amp;prod=SRPB" class="navlink">SRP Banner </a></b> <span style="COLOR: gray">&nbsp;(Pending:&nbsp;1&nbsp;of&nbsp;1)</span></span></td>

</tr>



<tr>
<td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>

<br><br>
<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"1621b6db8b","applicationID":"103016861","transactionName":"NV1TZkBVXBdVWk1RVgwXZEBbG0ERWUoWSEsNXERRRkdtC1JfXEpcBhZBWkI=","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":736,"atts":"GRpQEAhPTxk=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}</script>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Hi QHarr thanks for the reply i have edit my code.

Comment: Can you show more of your code and share an URL? Are there any form/frame/iframe tags to navigate? And did you try .FindElementByCss("a.navlink").Click or .FindElementByCss("a[href*='trans_id=1819']").Click The last one being more selective as may be more than one navlink on the page.

Comment: Yes there is frame tags to navigate.I have try your both code but not working.

Comment: Yes,There is frame tags to navigate.

Comment: Can you show more html including the frames? If you can find the frame name (if there is one) for example, you can use  .SwitchToFrame("frameName") first then try selecting. Depends how many frame tags. The element must also be inside the frame tag for this to matter.

Comment: Hi QHarr, Thanks for the reply i have edit my html code.

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to *click* on the desired element first you need to *Switch To the Frame* then lookout for the element and you can use the following solution:

```
Driver.Get "http://sums.99acres.com/sums/getmyproducts.php?trans_id=1819-T0639786"
Driver.Wait 5000
Driver.SwitchToFrame.FindElementByXPath("//frame[@name='left' and contains(@src,'http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php')]", timeout:=10000)
Driver.Wait 3000
Driver.FindElementByXPath("//a[@class='navlink' and contains(@href,'http://sums.99acres.com/sums/zedo_srp_products.php?module')][contains(.,'SRP Banner')]").Click
```

Comment: For vba though it prompts with argument not optional. Does it need syntax like Driver.SwitchToFrame Driver.FindElementByXPath("//frame[@name='left' and contains(@src,'http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php')]")  ? I have only ever used with string or numeric arguments in VBA. Sadly, I can't test that URL for geographic reasons I believe.

Comment: Which line `prompts with argument not optional`?

Comment: Hi i am getting error Compile error Argument not optional at Driver.SwitchToFrame.FindElementByXPath ("//frame[@name='left' and contains(@src,'http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php')]")

Comment: Try out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Hi DebanjanB, Now i am getting error-Run Time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method at Driver.SwitchToFrame (Driver.FindElementByXPath("//frame[@name='left' and contains(@src,'http://sums.99acres.com/sums/products_offered.php')]"))

Comment: Try out my updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to fit as a comment legibly. Can you try chucking the pageSource HTML into an HTMLDocument and clicking from there? Following code lines go in continuing from the Wait line you already have, reproduced below:

```
Driver.Wait 5000
Dim html As New HTMLDocument, ele As Object
html.body.innerHTML = Driver.PageSource

Set ele = html.getElementsByTagName("form")(0)
ele.querySelector("a[href*='trans_id=1819']").Click
```

I have left it in several stages so you can debug whether the ele is even set before attempting a click.

Comment: Hi QHaar i am getting error Run Time error '601' Application-defined or Object-defined error at html.body.innerHTML = Driver.PageSource

Comment: You would have a different error if HTML Object Library reference not added but I assume that is added? What happens with Msgbox  Left(Driver.PageSource,20)